# How to schedule a pod to a specific node, and the client can only access that node to get service?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have a k8s cluster with one master and three workers (worker1:192.168.1.1, worker2:192.168.1.2, worker3:192.168.1.3).

Now, I can use `nodeName` to force the k8s to schedule one pod to worker3. I want the client can only access that pod using the worker3 IP address and port(192.168.1.3), which means they can not reach that pod using the master, worker1, and worker2 addresses.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What leads to these specific requirements?  I don't think Kubernetes can meet them; it doesn't usually matter where a pod is scheduled, and for the most part different nodes are indistinguishable from each other.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I just want to have a try and want to see if it is possable.

Comment: @Erika I think you can do this using  NodePort services.

Comment: @hesmoh A NodePort Service will be accessible from outside the cluster on every node (including nodes that are added after the Service is created).